# Why the header is not expected?

Tags: python, download, multiprocess

As you see, I'm trying to make an multiprocess downloader.
It works well untill I open the final file: it's broken.
I check it but can't find any mistake. But It's probably the header download header is wrong and the Range value error.
this is the code

```
class MultiprocessDownload:
    def __init__(self, url, path, filename, thread_num):
        self.url = url
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename
        self.thread_num = thread_num
        self.threads = []
        self.head = requests.head(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}).headers
        self.length = int(self.head.get('Content-Length', False))
        print(self.length)
        self.proc = []
        self.lock = []
        for i in range(self.thread_num):
            self.proc.append(None)
            self.lock.append(None)
        if self.length == False: raise Exception('Thik file does not support multiprocess download')
        num = self.length // self.thread_num
        last = -1
        for i in range(1, thread_num + 1):
            self.threads.append([last + 1, num * i])
            last = num * i
        self.threads[-1:][0][1] += self.length % self.thread_num
        print(self.threads)
            
    def thread(self, num):
        self.lock[num] = _thread.allocate_lock()
        with self.lock[num]:
            header = {'Range': f'bytes=' + str(self.threads[num][0]) + '-' + str(self.threads[num][1])}
            print(header)
            self.proc[num] = 0
            req = requests.get(self.url, headers=header, stream = True)
            blk_size = self.threads[num][1] - self.threads[num][0]
            file = open('dl_block_' + str(num), 'wb')
            i = 0
            for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
                if chunk:
                    file.write(chunk)
                    i += 1
                    self.proc[num] = i * 512 / blk_size
            file.close()
        return 0
    
    def getDownloadInfo(self):
        info = []
        total = 0
        for i in range(self.thread_num):
            if None in self.proc: return 1
            info.append(str(self.proc[i] * 100) + '%')
            total += self.proc[i]
        info.append(str(total / self.thread_num * 100) + '%') #[*threads_info, total_info]
        return info

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.thread_num):
            print(i)
            _thread.start_new_thread(self.thread, (i,))
        time.sleep(10)
        locked = 1
        print(self.lock)
        while locked:
            print(self.getDownloadInfo())
            locked = 0
            for n in range(self.thread_num):
                if None in self.lock:
                    locked = 1
                    continue
                if self.lock[n].locked():
                    locked += 1
            print(locked)
            time.sleep(1)
        for num in range(self.thread_num):
            blk = open('dl_block_' + str(num), 'rb')
            target = open(self.path + self.filename, 'ab')
            target.write(blk.read())
            target.close()
            blk.close()
            os.remove('dl_block_' + str(num))
        print('file downloaded as', self.path + self.filename)
```

Some of its output:
[[0, 48967091], [48967092, 97934182], [97934183, 146901273], [146901274, 195868364], [195868365, 244835455], [244835456, 293802546], [293802547, 342769637], [342769638, 391736728], [391736729, 440703819], [440703820, 489670910], [489670911, 538638001], [538638002, 587605092], [587605093, 636572183], [636572184, 685539274], [685539275, 734506365], [734506366, 783473471]]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
{'Range': 'bytes=48967092-97934182'}
{'Range': 'bytes=244835456-293802546'}{'Range': 'bytes=195868365-244835455'}
{'Range': 'bytes=489670911-538638001'}{'Range': 'bytes=391736729-440703819'}{'Range': 'bytes=342769638-391736728'}{'Range': 'bytes=0-48967091'}{'Range': 'bytes=97934183-146901273'}
{'Range': 'bytes=146901274-195868364'}{'Range': 'bytes=440703820-489670910'}{'Range': 'bytes=293802547-342769637'}

{'Range': 'bytes=538638002-587605092'}{'Range': 'bytes=587605093-636572183'}
{'Range': 'bytes=685539275-734506365'}

{'Range': 'bytes=636572184-685539274'}{'Range': 'bytes=734506366-783473471'}

the thread's range is quite strange but I can't find where's wrong.

Comment: the downloads code block's length out of the length i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected that the program print out the range not in order, depending on which thread is **started** first rather than depending on which thread is **create** first.

You should change your code like this:

```py
        target = open(self.path + self.filename, 'wb')
        for num in range(self.thread_num):
            blk = open('dl_block_' + str(num), 'rb')
            target.write(blk.read())
            blk.close()
            os.remove('dl_block_' + str(num))
        target.close()
```

This change will create a target file when you first run it or rewrite the target file from the second running.

The code seems ugly although it works. More advice:

- use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run) library to implement this downloader
- using [barrier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) to wait all works done instead of sleep and while-loop
- `blk_size = self.threads[num][1] - self.threads[num][0] + 1`
- use `ls -l` to check the file size

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's wrong in the http request. It shows that it's return data is bigger than expected

Comment: @Player01 read the update ;-)

Comment: That works perfectly! With that, I even can launch a new thread while downloading and calculate the sizes make it integrate. Thanks for your help!